# d3 map tutorial - converting shp data

Tags: d3.js, topojson

Hei.
I have followed this tutorial: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

I have installed the tools needed successfully but when I do this part:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \
  subunits.json \
  ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

terminal tells me that I do not provide a datasource. So how exactly should the datasource look like? Do I need to put the whole path to the source (can someone post an example?)?
thanks for help.

Comment: The tutorial you've linked to is quite clear. Have you downloaded all the files and put them in the current directory?

Comment: which would be the current directory?

Comment: Whatever directory you're running the command in.

Comment: sorry but that is the problem. I don't understand what you mean by that... which directory is this installed? or how do I chose a directory to run the command in?

Comment: That depends on what OS you're running.

Comment: I'm running a macbook pro with OSX 10.9.2

Comment: Then open a terminal in the directory you've downloaded the files to.

Answer (score 2):

Lars is right.

You need to copy all the files that you've obtained from the natural earth vector for this specific map. If you've downloaded the vectors, you should be able to see these files.

```
ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.dbf
ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.prj
ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shx
```

You need all these files at the same location. 
You can (for simplicity) copy these files to the location where you have the ORG2OGR tool installed and then run the command that you have posted above.

The tutorial is quite succinct.